# Is there a good Node.js MVC framework in Coffeescript?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, coffeescript

Node.js is cool, but I am not happy with javascript with it's prototypes and other nuances.
Are there any live and supported MVC frameworks for Node.js written in Coffeescript? 
I've googled for a couple of days, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Why would the framework need to be written in Coffeescript?

Comment: Also, even though you write CoffeeScript, it will get _compiled_ into JavaScript still. You have to debug your code in JavaScript. It is a good idea to learn and understand JavaScript prototypes and its nuances.

Comment: @WiredPrairie to make it possible to simply extend base Coffeescript classes with my own, as I do in any OOP language

Comment: @Bulkan I understand it, but I don't like it

Comment: batman.js is in coffeescript. http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/

Comment: The framework doesn't have to be written in CoffeeScript for `class C extends FrameWorkClass` to work, Backbone for example. And you need to understand how JavaScript works to be effective in CoffeeScript whether you like it or not, just like you need to understand low level machine details to be an effective C programmer.

Comment: @muistooshort well, there are many methods to implement object-model in javascript, many ways to implement class inheritance, constructors, define objects, etc (I can implement them myself in different ways — on objects, on functions, on prototypes, with different inheritance, etc). And proper inheritance with coffee should work correct if framework internal classes are built in the same manner, as Coffee implements OOP. Thus yes, framework doesn't have to be written in CoffeeScript but must be compatible with it. And really it would be better, if it will be in Coffee.

Comment: @muistooshort And again: I understand js internals, I simply don't like them and want to make my life easier with CoffeeScript. And I want to read framework sources written in clean objective manner.